# ApostropheCMS Deployment Issue With Widget

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, node-modules, apostrophe-cms, apostrophe

I am a relative beginner to working in Apostrophe. I'd like to start off by saying its a pretty great ecosystem and I've enjoyed the experience so far. However, I've run into an issue thats a bit confusing.

I've been using it to build a site for a client and I've run into a very odd issue.  I have installed an instagram widget that I found via npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kwsites/cms-instagram-widgets) and used it on my local host with relatively no issues, it worked and I moved on with my life.

However now I'm trying to deploy the site and the Instagram widget is not showing up in the browser when viewing on the server. Again the widget shows up perfectly fine in the browser when viewing off my local host which would indicate it did not install correctly on the server but  after following all of the post install steps on the linked npm package, I am completely unsure of what to try next. 
I have confirmed that the @kwsites package folder is in public/modules/ directory

Any help/tips from any of the Apostrophe experts out there would be appreciated.

I am using stagecoach for deployment (again, a great product) and mechanic to manage nginx.  I don't know if any of this matters but the widget is making some API calls to Instagram, don't know if they would be affected by either of those tools.

EDIT: Inspection in safari yielded the following from my local host 
[image]

And the following from my server
[image]

It  just looks like the widget is not being generated and I cannot find any errors in the console.  Note I can add and remove a widget, I just can't get any content to generate on the server (but can on local host).

Comment: The API calls wouldn't be effected by using stagecoach or mechanic, maybe unless you don't have HTTPS set up with mechanic and that's required. So `public/modules/` is there on the remote server? If the widget is not showing up, I would expect errors on the server or in the console. Anything there?

Comment: My previous comment  needed correction.  I did set up https via mechanic. I agree that I don't think it is the problem. Yes, public/modules exists inside my latest deployment. 

If it would be useful/helpful in diagnosing what is happening, I can share the address of the current deployment.


The error I am recieving in the browser is: **DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME**

Comment: The first part of that error looks like a plugin warning. Probably unrelated, but it's often worth disabling plugins just in case. "HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" seems more relevant. I would dig into that. I see you posted an issue on the plugin repo, which is a good idea. My guess is that something is off with an Instagram URL.

Comment: From what I found it looked like it might have been my ad blocker.  The weird part was that the url worked fine off local host.  I think its possible that it may have been that the original developer registered the site url with Instagram legacy API as localhost:3000 so any developer could get it to work.  But in production, may have required re-registering. 

In any case, Instagram is discontinuing legacy API at the end of June.  I found a possible workaround [here](https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/instagram) that I am trying to adapt to an Apostrophe module using a Zapier rss feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as noted in the comments, I believe the issue was due to instagram's legacy api requiring site authorization.    However with Facebook pushing the new Instagam Basic Display API, the legacy is going to be killed at the end of this month anyway/apps will stop working.  So I found [this blog post](https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/instagram) and found it easily adaptable to an Apostrophe module.  It requires signing up for Zapier but a basic account is free and its a really interesting tool.  This solved my needs