# Critical Deployment Error ApostropheCMS Duplicate key error in Trash folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, apostrophe-cms, apostrophe

So I have been trying to create an embedded Instagram feed in ApostropheCMS.  After struggling with an npm module using the Instagram Legacy API (Detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165992/apostrophecms-deployment-issue-with-widget?noredirect=1#comment110001082_62165992)), I created an local Widget module based on this [idea](https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/instagram/).  It works surprisingly well.

However, when I was struggling I created a couple different "Instagram" pages and deleted them.  Now when I use stagecoach to deploy, I recieve the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: ButchsBBQ.aposDocs index: slug_1 dup key: { : "/trash/instagram" }
```

Is there a good way for me to resolve this? How can I get rid of things that I've already trashed?

Comment: It seems that this was resolved in the Apostrophe Discord chat: https://discordapp.com/channels/517772094482677790/517782236800745495/718235002504085605

Comment: Yes it was, I'll add a summary of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, the answer was provided in the apostrophe discord server.  This happened when I migrated the data base improperly.  Basically, I trashed the page on my local machine, migrated the database and then restored the database but before before refrashing my page,I believe  I trashed the same page on the server.  I ended up with two pages in the trash with the same slug key.

To solve this problem, the pages had to be dropped manually via mongo shell on both the local machine and server to proceed with deployment.